# Keyword Mobile Connect scenario

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sharing-keywords

We have contacts receiving SMS messages through a journey and being opted into the keyword by filling out a form and entering the journey. Now, we are also giving contacts an option to opt in to (hopefully) the same keyword via sms by texting the keyword, is it possible to have both be using the same keyword and not be receiving the same message multiple times?